# Autogenerate Client Code from Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have access to a private API's Swagger UI documentation, it looks like [this](https://swagger.io/swagger-ui/).

I would like to obtain the raw swagger file from these docs (somehow), place it in the [swagger editor](https://swagger.io/swagger-editor/) and use the client generator to autogenerate a java client. I reached out to the developer and they say they don't have the raw swagger/.yaml file.

My question is whether or not there's a way to obtain the raw swagger file from the Swagger UI API docs.

Comment: `File -> Convert and save as JSON`?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't have access to a file, just a web page with their Swagger UI API docs. Is there a file I could extract from the UI page to convert?

Comment: Isn't this menu button what you're looking for? https://i.imgur.com/fGPOtty.png

Comment: Yes, that would be great if I had the raw swagger yaml file, except the page I have access to is simply a Swagger UI API doc that looks like this: [https://imgur.com/a/bQfsj](https://imgur.com/a/bQfsj) - there is no menu at the top and there is no swagger code next to it like you would see in the swagger editor in your image.

Comment: Look at the network calls (in Developer Tools), it makes a call to a server to get the Swagger JSON.

Comment: Good call Ramon! It turned out to be in the network tab, /swagger/docs/v2 - I went there directly and I got the JSON to paste in the swagger editor and generate a client, thanks!! Will you repost as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are seeing the Swagger UI without the default wrapping tools ([the Swagger Editor with the menu](https://editor.swagger.io/) or [the Swagger UI with the URL bar at the top](http://petstore.swagger.io/)) you can still find the Swagger JSON by finding the link to it in the network tools:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools showing the loading of the swagger.json file]

In this demo case: `http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json`

Comment: Rolled back title change and grammatical edits to this post. The title is what the original question was and does accurately describe the information I was looking for as well as what someone may search for in the future to find this information. Grammatical edits and modification to the way I wanted to ask the question were unnecessary.

Comment: legend, was tryna figure this out!